# How to collaborate on a project in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I would like to know if it's possible to collaborate on a project in Xcode (like in Keynote). Here is a picture to show what I mean:

[image]

As you can see, there is a collaborate button in keynote that allows you to send an invitation to someone and be able to work together on the presentation in the same time (like on google drive).

I would like to know if this option is available in Xcode so that me and my partner can work in parallel on a project (she adds things in the same time that I do).

Comment: Not in this way, no. You should use GIT or other code versioning software.

Comment: I see thank you for your answer.

Comment: Try [GitHub](https://github.com/).